# Overloading (),[] operators in c++

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, operator-keyword

How would you overload the () and [] operators in c++? Justify with some code.
Won't it affect the integrity of the programming language?

Comment: In Which language? OOP and C++ are not synonymous.

Comment: In which language? I would guess C++

Comment: -1 For "How would you... give some examples." This question has good potential (e.g. the last bit and "pitfalls"), but this is not it. A tutorial -- not SO -- is what you need for the first bit.

Comment: @vivek - Look at the related questions at the right. I am sure you could find some.

Comment: but. Couldn't find any example searching in the internet. So asked for example, thinking i could get one here,

Comment: I would strongly suggest not overloading the '()' operator in anything but small personal code experimentations. It can easily be confused with constructor syntax, making code using it hard to maintain/debug.

Comment: @Darcy : Not to be impolite, but you could not be more wrong. `operator()` is the basis of function objects (aka functors), which, in conjunction with iterators, are the basis of interacting with the C++ standard library itself. In modern C++ code, `operator()` is the operator that should be overloaded __most__ in user code (aside from `operator=`).

Comment: @ildjarn : Fair point, maybe I should be going back and hitting a few text books.

Answer (score 2):

It can't affect integrity of the programming language simply because operator overloading can be performed for user-defined types only. It is impossible to overload operators for built-in types in C++. You cannot change the behavior of `[]` with data pointers (that covers the arrays as well). You cannot change the behavior of `()` with function pointers. In other words, core language features of C++ cannot be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
class Test {
  const int size = 128;
  int data[size];
public:
  Test() { 
    // allocate memory for data, etc.
  }

  int& operator[](int index) {
    return data[index];
  }
};
```

Comment: what if the there is a array of the objects? Won't it affect the native [] operation?

Comment: Unless you're subclassing from a class that has the operator[] defined, there isn't native [] operator. If you

Comment: It is only an issue if you're subclassing something that has [] defined. E.g. std::vector. You probably don't want to alter the default behavior of [] in that case. Just because C++ allows you to do a lot of things, doesn't mean you should do them :)